# Google MAIL not arriving - relay not allowed

Tags: domain-name-system, sendmail, gmail, google

I have a server with sendmail, hosting my domain mind-zone.nl, i changed the MX records to point to the server. When I use Hotmail or any other client the email arrives and everything is fine. ONLY mail from GMAIL server is bounced and gmail returns "relay denied".

I have set all the virtual server host settings etc, from command line I can send mails as well, hotmail works, etc. Just not gmail.

The strange thing is, this is what gmail returns:
Look at the lower part: "Received by" it returns some IP address which is not mine and has absolutely nothing with my domain. While when I do a NSLOOKUP and change to google's DNS server it will state that the IP Address for my domain is correctly pointing at my server.

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain.
We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error.
The error that the other server returned was: 554 554 5.7.1: Relay access denied (state 14).

----- Original message -----

MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.14.37.138 with SMTP id y10mr3421504eea.43.1297665573901; Sun,
 13 Feb 2011 22:39:33 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.14.29.75 with HTTP; Sun, 13 Feb 2011 22:39:33 -0800 (PST)
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the bounce?

Answer (score 0):

Were you hosting email for the domain at Google in the past? If so, have you gone through the appropriate procedures so that Google stops hosting it?